# Laravel : Select from two tables where column in table two =value using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables
table 1 = NewsCollection
table 2 = NewsConllectionTranslation

here is the models

NewsCollection

```
class NewsCollection extends \Eloquent
{
    use \Dimsav\Translatable\Translatable;

    public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'content'];
    public $translationModel = 'NewsCollectionTranslation';

    public function newsTrans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('NewsCollectionTranslation', 'news_collection_id');
    }
}
```

NewsConllectionTranslation

```
class NewsCollectionTranslation extends \Eloquent
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'news_collection_translations';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content'];

    public function transNews()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('NewsCollection', 'news_collection_id');
    }
}
```

and here is the show controller

```
public function show($title)
    {
        $news = NewsConllectionTranslation::with('newsTrans')->where('title', $title)->first();
        return View::make('portal.news.show', compact('news'));
    }
```

What I need to do is

```
->where('title', $title)->first();
```

should be selected from `NewsConllectionTranslation` and I don't want to lose the translation so I don't want to select from `NewsConllectionTrnslation` first

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$news = NewsConllectionTranslation::whereHas('newsTrans', function ($query) use ($title) {
    $query->where('title', $title);
})->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this

```
 public function show($title)
    {
        $news = NewsConllectionTranslation::with(['newsTrans' => function ($query) use($title) {
                $query->where('title', $title)->first();
            }])


        return View::make('portal.news.show', compact('news'));
    }
```